# Ident Authentication failed for user Centos 8 Postgresql12

Tags: linux, postgresql, configuration, centos, pgadmin

So I have problem with ident Authentication on Centos 8 and postgresql-12.
Errors below during server addition::::
[pgadmin4 error creation server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWY21.png)

connection on localhost:
[postgres connect localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDeAE.png)

I really tried many answers but no one worked for me.
pg_nba.conf file now has following strings:

1. local all all trust
2. local all all md5
3. host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
4. host all all ::1/128 md5
5. host all all 10.1.1.0

File pg_ident.conf is empty so I don't have any mapping,
Help me ples

but after execution following lines I have entered in console

- su postgres
- psql

Comment: The pg_hba.conf you show is not the one in use.  Either you edited the wrong file, or didn't successfully reload the configuration after editing it.

Comment: The last line of the shown pg_hba has a syntax error (it doesn't specify a method), so if you tried to start the server with it it would fail.  If you tried to reload the server, it would just keep using the old settings.

Comment: @jjanes Thank u for the fast response, so I added md5 in the last line. But result is the same, after with command sudo systemctl reload postgresql-12 I made reload(I think so) file pg_nba.conf is in directory /var/lib/pgsql/12/data->pg_nba.conf so i dont think here u see some error but from another point of view i've seen that some buddies configured ident server i didn't touch that guy, instead i have authd for centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was just problem with ident server which I didn't launch